# Get empty collection of embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, odm

I want to get a collection of embedded documents. I put data into the database like this:

```
$dm->getRepository('BundleUserBundle:User')->addRatedPostById($user->getId(), new RatedPost($id, $type));
```

...which works fine. Now I see new data in mongo console, but when I'm trying to get this data via the `getRatedPosts()` method, it return *null* instead of the ArrayCollection. Whats wrong?

Context looks like this:

```
class User extends BaseUser {
    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedMany(targetDocument="RatedPost")
     */
    protected $ratedPosts;

   /**
    * Add ratedPosts
    *
    * @param Bundle\UserBundle\Document\RatedPost $ratedPosts
    */
    public function addRatedPost(\Bundle\UserBundle\Document\RatedPost $ratedPosts)
    {
        $this->ratedPosts[] = $ratedPosts;
    }

   /**
    * Remove ratedPosts
    *
    * @param Bundle\UserBundle\Document\RatedPost $ratedPosts
    */
    public function removeRatedPost(\Bundle\UserBundle\Document\RatedPost $ratedPosts)
    {
        $this->ratedPosts->removeElement($ratedPosts);
    }

   /**
   * Get ratedPosts
   *
   * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $ratedPosts
   */
   public function getRatedPosts()
   {
       return $this->ratedPosts;
   }

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class RatedPost
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Int
     */
    public $post;

   /**
    * @MongoDB\String
    */
    public $rate;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same problems: saving was no problem but fetching the embedded document was. Turned out it was a "Symfony" caching problem (also on app_dev.php). Have you tried to remove your cache, this worked for me!

Comment: That worked for me too and could have saved hours of trial & error had I seen it earlier.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! This answer save my day. I spent over a hour to understand why this f**king array stayed empty ^^ Thanks again :)